# What is the correct type of props to replace any?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I have this current App function originally in js which I would like to change to Typescript:

```
export default function App(props: any): JSX.Element {
  console.log(`props: ${props.studentList}`);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="React Native">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="React Native"
          component={HomeScreen}
          initialParams={{studentList: props.studentList}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

a sample of props would be:

```
props= { studentlist: [{"name":"Jonh", "course":"Typescript"},{"name":"Jane","course":"Javascript"}]}
```

What would be the way to replace `any`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define types for your props, BEFORE the function:

```
type Student = {
  name: string;
  course: string;
};

type AppProps = {
  studentList: Student[];
};
```

Then, first declare the Stack and then the functional as a functional component:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ studentList }: AppProps) => {
  console.log(`props: ${studentList}`);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="React Native">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="React Native"
          component={HomeScreen}
          initialParams={{ studentList }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```